# Form Activate event is not firing

Tags: vb.net, events, mdi

I am using VB.Net for my Windows application. I will open two child form from MDI. Both forms  will open. Now if I will go from form1 to form2 then `Activate` event for form2 will not fire.
I dont know why this happen. Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Deactivate += new EventHandler(Form1_Deactivate);
this.Activated += new EventHandler(Form1_Activated);
```

Try those eventhandlers (C#, should be similar in VB).

Tipp: You can also ask for the FormWindowState eg.:

```
if (FormWindowState.Normal == WindowState)
```

Comment: For vb.net: AddHandler Form1_Activated, AddressOf Form1_Activated

Comment: How does this answer the question? It says that the `Activate` event is not firing. It doesn't ask how to hook up a handler to the `Activate` event. This is way simpler in VB.NET, by the way. Just use the `Handles` keyword...